# "constant" gtk+ signal for a GtkLabel

Tags: c++, gtk, signals

Is there such a thing as a "constant" gtk+ signal, that is activated permanently? I'm in first steps into gtk, and would like to constantly update a `GtkLabel` during the execution of the program.

Answer (score 2):

The functions `g_timeout_add`, `g_idle_add` and related are probably what you are looking for, see [1].

[1] https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html